# RESTful Web Service using Node js

Tags: node.js, rest

I am new to node js and trying to publish a RESTful web service with it. I found few [tutorials](http://css.dzone.com/articles/writing-restful-web-services) online but they are not very explanatory or meant for advanced users.

I did check rectify framework. But it seems to appropriate for advanced Node JS users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might benefit from taking a look at a few of the frameworks that are out there that make that sort of thing easier.

Take a look at [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) or [hapi.js](http://spumko.github.io/) and see how they build routes, etc.

How new are you to RESTful services in general?

Comment: Fairly new. Know it conceptually. Mostly worked on SOAP services

Comment: Thanks. Can you point out a tutorial to learn restify step by step?

Comment: No, sorry. Perhaps a more general Node or Express tutorial would be more suitable to get the hang of how Node/Express work; restify isn't all that different, and has pretty good documentation.

Comment: After the fact, but worth reading Martin Fowler's blog regarding the Richardson Maturity Model - http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Answer (score 0):

restify and loopback seems to be a better framework option for REST API's in node.Again it all depends on your use case when selecting a framework. If you want to create something very simple and high performant write your API with native node.js modules only .